# How to select Linux temp/tmp/temporary directory overflow disk

Tags: linux, tmpfs

On linux, temporary files are stored on a ramdisk:

```
tmpfs                  15G  4.0K   15G   1% /dev/shm
```

However, if there are several large files in /tmp/ I would assume that the files overflow onto disk? In such a case, if the machine has slower and faster disks, it would be preferable the faster disks to be used.

How does this work exactly and how can we configure on Linux where the overflow goes to?

Answer (score 4):

`tmpfs` is the name of the RAM based filesystem, but it doesn't have to be mounted on `/tmp` or even used for traditional "temporary files". The example you've pasted is mounted on `/dev/shm`, which has nothing to do with `/tmp`, and so `/tmp` is probably just real disk.

Linux has no built in mechanism for `/tmp` "oveflow", so you'd have to set something up manually to achieve this. There is some distinction between `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` (IIRC `/var/tmp` tends to be used for bigger files), so mounting a `tmpfs` on `/tmp` and leaving `/var/tmp` on real disk may be good enough.

If you actually want it to overflow you'll have to setup a union filesystem like [unionfs](http://unionfs.filesystems.org/) or [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/). These filesystems take multiple underlying directories and expose them as a single mountpoint. You can configure the priority of the underlying directories so that the `tmpfs` is used first, then the fastest disk, etc.

Comment: Any copy-paste examples how to achieve these?

i) mount tmpfs on /tmp
ii) setup a union filesystem like unionfs or aufs so that the tmpfs is used first, then the fastest disk, etc.

Comment: You explicitly SHOULD NOT use `tmpfs` for `/var/tmp`. [Its files must survive reboots](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s15.html).